# React Router Dom Redirect needs to refresh the page to work

Tags: reactjs, redirect, anchor, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom and I experience a weird behavior when redirecting. I'm trying to redirect from / to /something. So I used:

```
        <Switch>
            <Redirect
                exact
                from='/'
                to='/something'
            />
            <Route
                component={Garden}
                exact
                path='/something'
            />
        </Switch>
```

When I open localhost:3000/ I get redirected to localhost:3000/something but the page is blank. When I refresh the page or access /something directly, the page is displayed as expected.

A similar behavior happens when I use react-router-hash-link to handle anchor tags. When setting the scrolling to smooth scroll, I can see the page smoothly scrolling but as soon as it reaches the tag, the page becomes blank. For it to work, I need to refresh the page which is quite inconvenient.

thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code block that you have shown in the question looks good.

You might be configuring the router incorrectly.

[See working demo here I created here](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-issue-fix-whtx5?file=/src/App.js) which uses your `switch` code. Check the router configuration and apply it to your code base.

**Router**

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Router>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/something" />
          <Route component={Home} exact path="/something" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**component**

```js
const Home = props => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => res.map(user => user.username))
      .then(userNames => setVal(userNames));
  });
  return <div>Home - {val}</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't surround the block with <Router></Router>. Oops.  react-router-hash-link wasn't actually needed. It made the issue appear more complex. <a href> worked fine.
 Again, Thank you!

Comment: np .. happy to help :)

Comment: So in my case I was import Router instead of BrowserRouter from react-router-dom.
Just a simple reminder in case someone appears here. Thanks gdb